# Can two `Comparable` protocol conformances be used simultaneously?

Tags: swift

I’m learning swift and just practicing myself, creating something similar to code and can not understand. How do I create two different conformances to the same Protocol in one program? Is it even possible??

When the code is executed, it produces an error.

[image]

I tried to write a second protocol conformance, but I can’t. I understand a little because I just started.

Comment: Please check out [ask], including the section on including code as text and not an image

Comment: Hey Denis! Just to clarify, these are protocol _conformances_. "`Class` _conforms to_ equatable". There's only one protocol here: `Equatable`. I've edited your question to fix the terms. Now please, include your code... *as code*. Nobody wants to spend their time transcribing text from screenshots.

Comment: As Alexander said, use the code formatting tools in the editor and post your code as code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, because it would be ambigious. If I write `englishClass < mathClass`, which conformance should be used? Should they be compared by grade averages, or by their students? How would the compiler know?

The way to solve this in Swift is to either:

1. Use a custom comparatison block, e.g. for sorting: `classes.sort { classA, classB in classA.students < classB.students }`
2. Make two structs that wraps your `class Class`, each of which conform to `Equatable` in a different way. E.g. `struct ClassStudentComparator: Comparable { ... }` and  `stuct ClassGradeAverageComparator { ... }`.